# Foreign Key Error with Table that has FK when Inserting in Table that originates the FK

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have been trying to run this query in php:

```
INSERT INTO inventory (prodID, userID, qty) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM products WHERE cod = :COD), 9, :QTY);
```

It didn't execute, so I put it in mysql workbench to see if there was an error.
All the times I did that, this appeared:

*Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`expiration`, CONSTRAINT `inventoryID` FOREIGN KEY (`inventoryID`) REFERENCES `inventory` (`inventoryID`))*

I don't understand why there's an error on the FK constrain of expiration. InventoryID is a PK AI of inventory. Can anyone help me?

Edit:

Table schemas:

*Products*

- ID - PK AI
- cod
- name
- standard_expiration

*Inventory*

- inventoryID - PK AI
- userID - FK
- prodID - FK
- qty

*Users*

- userID - PK AI
- name
- key

*Expiration*

- ExpID - PK AI
- inventoryID - FK
- input_Date
- estimated_exp

I have a trigger after insert on Inventory to register the last ID and input date on expiration while also calculating the estimated_exp by adding current time + standard_exp.I wrote it like this:

```
SET @inv = (SELECT last_insert_id());
SET @prod = (SELECT (prodID) from inventory WHERE inventoryID = @inv);
SET @stdexp = (SELECT (standard_exp) from products WHERE ID = @prod);
SET @estmexp = ( SELECT ADDDATE(curdate(), @stdexp));

INSERT INTO expiration (inventoryID, input_Date, estimated_exp)
VALUES (@inv, curdate(), @estmexp);
```

About the PHP:
I used PDO::errorInfo() and got `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Can you add table schemas to question? Likely not issue but I would write the query as `INSERT INTO inventory (prodID, userID, qty) SELECT ID, 9, :QTY FROM products WHERE cod = :COD`. You also should look into error handling in PHP, you should be able to get that error in PHP as well.